# Spring security disable while testing

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a app written with JSF and Spring (transactions and IoC). The app is secured with Spring security (pretty complex due the fact that i use ACLs). The flow through app is:
JSF Managed Bean -> Service Class -> DAO class -> DB  and the other way around.

The interface implemented by the tested method looks like :

```
public interface MyService extends GenericService {

    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#oId,'com.mycompany.core.entity.MyObject','read')")
    public abstract MyObject getMyObject(Long oId);
}
```

The test for specified method:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:/applicationContext.xml","classpath:      /applicationContext-test.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback =  true)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MyServiceImplIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void testGetMyObject(){
        myService.getMyObject();
    }
}
```

As it can be seen I use two xml files for configuring spring (one for tests and one for non test).
My problem is that for this entire test class I want to eliminate the spring security annotations that are on the real methods.
My first was to override the  element which now looks like this :

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="methodExpressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>
```

with

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="disabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="methodExpressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>
```

But it seems that this element cannot be overridden in other files.
Any other ideas of how can i achieve the same effect ?

PS. the components versions are :

```
<org.springframework.version>4.0.7.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>

<org.springframework.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
```

Comment: split your configuration in application config (services etc.) and security config and for testing don't load the security part.

Comment: I have my config already split but I cannot skip security part entirely because it is referenced in other files. And also for some tests I want to run security also :)

Comment: Then in those tests load the additional file. What is referenced? The fact that there is a `@PreAuthorize` doesn't mean the config has to be there. It is just meta-data.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have other beans that depends to beans from security, ie AclServiceHelper (which is used to create AC entries) depends on org.springframework.security.acls.model.MutableAclService.. and so on